# What is currently the best way to connect Rails on Google Container Engine (GKE) with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

The biggest problem I understand here is managing IPs.  The rails pods IPs will be dynamic so will not be able to whitelist them.  So how do I get Rails access to the Google Cloud SQL database in a secure way without knowing the IPs of the Rails containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the Cloud SQL Proxy in your pod which will allow you to connect to Cloud SQL via a local UNIX socket: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy#to-use-from-kubernetes

Comment: Yeah, I just recently saw that.  It seems like the only real way, though it's still pretty gross as it requires creating a persistent disk which is also annoyingly non-trivial :/  But it's what we've got.  Thanks!

Comment: which part requires a persistent disk? I'm not too knowledgeable about GKE but I don't think this requires a persistent disk

Comment: Yeah, it loos like it does from that link  "This GCE PD must already exist." to keep the secret

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- that seems incorrect, I'll ask someone to take a look. A Kubernetes secret does not require a PD volume.

Comment: Great, will love to hear back!